# Limit the maximum speed of a UIScrollView? Or clear the saved render of a tile?

Tags: objective-c, ios, svg

I have a UIScrollView with lots of complex vector graphics rendered in tiled UIWebViews.

The problem is that there are unsightly visual glitches when the view is scrolled quite quickly (several, consecutive quick swipes) because the reused tiles contain a snapshot of the old render before they get refreshed. The end result is that the tiles moving out of the screen appear to immediately come back in through the other side, before their contents are suddenly redrawn.

I'm hoping theres some way to limit the maximum speed that a scrollview can be flicked at. I could just disable flick scrolling, but that wouldn't be ideal.

If there's a way to clear the saved render of the UIWebView, that might also be a good band-aid fix.

Comment: Scrollception. It's a scroll within a scroll.

Comment: Disabling scrolling on the UIWebViews does away with that problem. I agree that it isn't ideal, but SVG support in iOS is downright pathetic. Tried SVGKit but it doesn't support a lot of basic elements like text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Hide the UIWebViews when they begin loading a page and show them when they finish via the UIWebView's delegate ([`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)).

In [`webViewDidStartLoad:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad%3a) hide the UIWebView (i.e. `myWebView.hidden = YES;`). In [`webViewDidFinishLoad:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) show it again.

It may be better to hide the webView elsewhere in your code, but showing it in the webViewDidFinishLoad: is a good idea.  You'll also want a background for the scrollview since you'll see behind the UIWebView's using this method.

### Solution 2

Change the UIScrollView's [`decelerationRate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW44)

> **decelerationRate**
>
> A floating-point value that determines the rate of deceleration after
>   the user lifts their finger.

```
@property(nonatomic) float decelerationRate
```

> **Discussion**
>
> Your application can use the UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal and
>   UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast constants as reference points for
>   reasonable deceleration rates.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>
> UIScrollView.h

Comment: Now why didn't i think of these earlier..? Never been so thankful for the power of the internet.

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: This site is awesome for getting answers.  So, did one of the two solutions work out for you?  I'm assuming you liked the first one more as it seemed the more elegant approach, but I wouldn't be surprised if you did them both.

Comment: did them both, then set a background image to indicate unrendered tiles. now there's feedback to the user if they scroll so insanely fast that nothing gets rendered for a few seconds!

i'm hoping for better svg support in future iOS releases. each tile renders in about 100-200ms right now.. perceptibly glitchy, but still usable.